# Hiding implementation details using interfaces when arbitrary implementations not allowed

Tags: c#, api, oop

I'm building a public API for our application, using C#. I have a set of facade classes on top of DTOs used with a WCF client. It allows the API consumer to fetch, update, create, etc., from a database application. Standard stuff: Customer has a collection of Orders, Order has a collection of Line Items, etc.

The facade classes all derive from a common base class and override methods that do validation, reading/writing the DTOs, and other plumbing stuff, all using various internal types. I'm using a factory for creating new objects and fetching existing ones.

The question now is how best to expose the classes through the API while minimizing exposure of implementation details.

Interfaces seem like the obvious approach as the simplest way to limit what's exposed (and may in the end be necessary anyway, as a COM-compatible interface is under consideration). The problem with the interface approach is that internally my code will be dependent on particular implementations of the interfaces.

Suppose I have an ICustomer interface exposing my CustomerFacade, and IOrder exposing OrderFacade. Externally, ICustomer has a collection of IOrders. But internally, the CustomerFacade has a collection of OrderFacades. If the client application adds a new IOrder to a customer, I have to check that the IOrder is really an OrderFacade previously created from my factory, and not some other object outside my control that implements IOrder. That's because internally I need an order to be able to do a lot more than what an IOrder can do.

Practically speaking this doesn't much matter--users of the API are not going to be trying to create their own Order implementations. But it feels inelegant to me, like an abuse of what the interface contract is supposed to mean.

Exposing the facade classes directly isn't great, because the entire class hierarchy has to get exposed, along with the internal types used by protected methods, and that clutters up the API with types that the consumer won't be using and doesn't need to know about.

The other alternative I can think of is another layer of encapsulation: An Order that contains a private OrderFacade and only exposes the members that should be public. But this seems like a lot of extra code for limited benefit.

I considered abstract base classes but that doesn't work any better than exposing the facade classes, due to the inheritance structure. For example, if I have a ServiceItem that inherits from CatalogItem, introducing an abstract ServiceItemBase in between still requires me to expose all the protected methods in CatalogItem.

Any recommendations on these approaches, or an alternative I haven't looked at?

Comment: you can always implement your OrderFacade to be constructable with OrderId and forget about interfaces altogether. Your customers are not gonna reinvent how your orders work, they just want to put in a number and get an answer. Take a look at Microsoft's own C# APIs - there are rarely interfaces and they are there only when needed, such as COM, and you still don't know or care about how they work. All you want is to give the Word API a file name and get a Word document back, not to implement IDocument yourself

Comment: @StenPetrov Thanks, but I don't understand how that addresses the question of how best to hide the internal details I don't want leaking into the API.

Comment: You already have services - that's where most (if not all) the magic should happen. The client side of the API should be mostly to facilitate calls to the service (validation, config handling etc). What I'm talking about is not to jump into abstracting more than necessary (interface, abstract classes, factories etc).

Answer (score 0):

That seems pretty complex. I don't know the business problems you're trying to solve, so I don't know why there's the need for the various facades. If users will be using your api for data manipulation, you could consider using commands to modify the data, and queries to return DTO's that contain only the data the client will need.

[http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

This is a great book that might help.

Comment: Looks like a good reference. I'll take a look and see if there's something there that I can apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could also expose abstract classes with no public constructors instead of interfaces. This has the additional advantage that abstract classes can be extended as a non-breaking change, which is not true for interfaces.

Using the *internal* access modifier enables the hiding of members that should not be visible outide the implementing assembly.

Comment: I should have mentioned that option in the question; I've updated to address that. Abstract bases don't work for me here because they're still inheriting from (and thus exposing the protected members of) classes above them.

Comment: Isn't that why the internal access modifier was provided?

Comment: Good point. I could change all the protected members to be internal instead. That exposes some things outside the class within the assembly, but that's not a big problem in this case.